# Why can't I access the 'name' of an object when looping through the scene's objects?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I am trying to delete all the objects that start with 'LTR' but am getting the following error:  'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

```
for obj in enumerate(bpy.context.scene.objects):
    namestr=obj.name #this throws the error
    if len(namestr)>=3:
        name2=namestr[3:]
        if name2=='LTR':
            delete_object(namestr) #this is a function that deletes the object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a *tuple* for each element from any given iterable and its position based on the actual iteration. Proof using the *Console*:

```
>>> for i in enumerate(["Hello","World"]):
>>>     print (i)
(0, "Hello")
(1, "World")
```

A *tuple* is a [composite data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type), composed out of *two elements* `(item1, item2)`. If you want to access its individual components `(left, right)` you can either use the index operator `[]` or create 2 variables for the actual return value (tuple) on the fly: `left, right = ("Hello", "World")`:

```
>>> my_tuple = ("Hello", "World")
>>> my_tuple[0]
"Hello"

left, right = ("Hello", "World")
>>> left
"Hello"
```

Means in your case that you can't access the object and its name this way because the returned *tuple* by the `enumerate()` function in your loop has no `name` property. Proof using the *Console* again:

```
>>> for ob in enumerate(C.scene.objects):
...     print (ob)
(0, bpy.data.objects['Cube'])
(1, bpy.data.objects['Light'])
(2, bpy.data.objects['Camera'])
```

In summary: you have to find a way *splitting the components of the tuple* if you want to access each element separately which basically leads into the following pattern:

```
>>> for left, right in enumerate(C.scene.objects):
...     print (left, right, "Name:", right.name)
0 <bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>, Name: Cube
1 <bpy_struct, Object("Light")> Name: Light
2 <bpy_struct, Object("Camera")> Name: Camera
```

---

Also notice that python has a lot of awesome tools dealing with strings. In order to determine whether a string is part of a another string (substring), you could use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) to test its "membership":

```
>>> "ell" in "HelloWorld"
True
```

To remove the objects, you might want to create some kind of *black list* before removing it. The following example removes all objects in the scene that have "Cam" in their name (substring):

```
import bpy

objects_to_remove = []

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if "Cam" in ob.name:
        objects_to_remove.append(ob)

bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objects_to_remove})
```

There is also [`str.startswith(prefix)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) returning `True` if the string begins with the `prefix` passed:

```
>>> "Hello World".startswith("Hell")
True
```

The following example removes all found objects whose names begin with "Cam":

```
import bpy

objects_to_remove = []

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.name.startswith("Cam"):
        objects_to_remove.append(ob)

bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objects_to_remove})
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use `enumerate`, an item in the list *and* an index/counter of where you are in the loop is returned to the variable (`obj`) instead of just the item. This is why you get the error, because in this case `obj` is a tuple (`(index, listItem)`) which does not have a `name` property itself.

The common loop syntax when using `enumerate` is:

```
for index, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.scene.objects):
```

`obj` will now contain the actual object as expected.

However, if you don't need an index of where you are in the loop you do not need to use `enumerate`. Remove it and it will work fine, e.g.:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
```

You could also access the second item in the tuple when trying to access the `name`:

```
namestr=obj[1].name
```